# Green function for interacting system

Tags: condensed-matter, greens-functions

> If we can diagonalize our interacting Hamiltonian then can we write a Green's function like we do for a non-interacting system? Green's function here means Matsubara in frequency-momentum space,
>   $G(w,k)=w-E(k)$.

Comment: There are many different kinds of Green's functions (time-ordered, retarded/advanced, Matsubara, Keldysh, etc.), and I don't think it is obvious what your notation means. Perhaps you could add the definitions of the quantities that you refer to, and provide some more context for your question?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can write the green function in $G(w,k)=w-E(k)$ form if you have diagnolized your hamiltonian